# Retrieve Data with one query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

## given a profile ID get Orders

```
@route.get("/profileId_order/{profileID}", dependencies=[Depends(check_active)], tags=["profile"])
def profileId_order(profileID: int):
    profile = db.query(Profilemodel).filter(Profilemodel.id==profileID).first()

    # if given profile_id is not exist it will raise error else return profile.
    if profile is None:       
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail="Resource Not Found")

    result = db.query(Ordermodel).filter(profile.profileName==Ordermodel.purchaseByName).all()

    # if given name is not matched it will raise error else return profile.
    if result is None:       
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail="Resource Name Not Found")

    return result
```

---

In above code I am getting orders details from order table with profileId(profile table),
there are two query in the code to retrieve data.

---

How can we retrieve data with one query?

example:

## Given a product name get all profiles who purchase that product

python

```
@route.get("/product_name/{product_name}", dependencies=[Depends(check_admin)], tags=["order"])
def get_productName_profile(product_name:str):
    result = []
    for c, i in db.query(Ordermodel.purchaseByName,Profilemodel).filter(Ordermodel.purchaseByName==Profilemodel.profileName and product_name==Ordermodel.productName).all():
        result.append(i)

    #pro = db.query(Profilemodel.profileName).all()

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the join function. This can be achieved via raw SQL query or by sqlalchemy API

example:

```
result = list(db.query(Ordermodel).join(Profilemodel, Profilemodel.profileName == Ordermodel.purchaseByName).filter(Profilemodel.id==profileID).all())
```

However, I see you want firstly to check for the profile existence anyway and return a 404 response in case there isn't one with this ID. In that case you cannot avoid the two queries if you still want that error back.

Comment: Hey @sardar-jagpreet-singh , does the above answer your question? If so please accept the answer, thanks!